# Make a non member function constant

Tags: c++, constants

I have a requirement of making a non-member function as constant i.e. I want to enforce that it mustn't allow any modification of global variables.

I know it is not  possible for non-member functions but was wondering if there is a workaround for that.

One way of what I was thinking is to declare a separate class with a constant member function for this and access const global variables. But unfortunately it allows access and modification of non constant global variables in a constant member function(why??).

Comment: take a const reference to the parameter?

Comment: And that's why you don't use globals.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore you mean globals?

Comment: @BarışUşaklı I mean globals :)

Comment: I don't think there's a language construct for making the global scope "const". You'd have to establish code-conventions and stick to them. It would be cool though to mark functions as "side effect free" and have the compiler enforce that.

Comment: Const class functions will prohibit modification of class-variables, but _not_ of _global_ variables.

Comment: if you really must use globals, which I doubt, you could instead put all of them in a class and make an instance of that class global. Then you can control access to the variables as you like.

Comment: `constexpr` may (or may not) be sufficient for your needs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `const`-qualifier on a member function of a class `T` doesn't mean that the function has no side effects: it means that function's implicit `this` parameter has the type `const T*`. In other words, the function cannot modify non-static data members (well, not easily anyway).

There's no standard way to enforce that a function has no side effects (so-called "pure" functions).

Answer (score 3):

> But unfortunately it allows access and modification of non constant global variables in a constant member function(why??).

Because global variables aren't part of the class. Global variables are global. If you don't want everyone to have access, don't make them global.

The constness only applies to member functions accessing other (non-mutable) members of the class. It doesn't mean "this function won't change anything anywhere ever"

Answer (score 1):

It's allowed in C++, but you're bound by more rules than just the one you want for globals

You have to declare your function `constexpr`. This means the function must be of a form that can be evaluated by the compiler. Obviously you can't modify variables, since they don't exist yet, so your globals are safe. But you can't do it sneakily either, by calling another non-`constexpr` function. No loops, nothing fancy, just one return statement.

Answer (score 0):

As said I'd stay away from globals, but a possibility is to wrap them all in a single class, since then you can make use of const member functions, and make an instance of that class global. Super simple example:

```
class Globals
{
public:
  Globals( int valueA ) :
    valueA( valueA )
  {
  }

  int ValueA() const
  {
    return 
  }

  //this one can be read/written to so no real need for getter/setter
  //unless you want thread-safety, then you'd add a getter/setter
  //with a mutex inside
  int valueB;

private:
  int valueA;
};

//somewhere in the source
Globals globals( 2 );
```